# An error occurred while calling o170.save. java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=1522, contentLength=1470 on glue job

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I'm getting the error: An error occurred while calling o170.save. java.io.IOException: Unexpected end of stream pos=1522, contentLength=1470 when writing to a delta table. I only get the error in some occasions, most of the time it works fine.

I don't understand why it only gives the error some times so I haven't try anything yet.